# Running Jenkins Slaves on old operating systems

Tags: linux, java, jenkins

I have a (quite old) Jenkins installation that I'd like to upgrade. Unfortunately, some jobs require to be built on an old operating system which cannot run Java 7 and hence cannot run the slave.jar from Jenkins. Is there a way aside from using SSH and a lot of copying back and forth of files manually to support build nodes not being able to run Java 7?